Text Field and Drop Down should have same height in row
I tried to make both equal height but its only applicable to one device, but for diff devices its changing
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              "Age",
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: DeviceSize.isTablet ? 12 : 6),
            TextFormField(
              controller: ageController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: "Age",
                isDense: true,
                errorText: ageErrorMessage,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 12),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Gender",
              style: textStyle,
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: DeviceSize.isTablet ? 12 : 6),
            DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 14.5)),
                hint: Text(
                  'Gender',
                  style: textStyle,
                ),
                value: selectedGender,
                validator: validate,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                items: genders.map((String gender) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: gender,
                    child: Text(
                      gender,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? value) {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),

I tried sizedbox, Container also, even dropdown button etc etc,  but no effect. Can you help to make height of both widgets same.
I need proper and good way to align their heights for all devices.

You can use the MediaQuery to adapt your height to all devices, example:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3

But i had used your code to replicate the error and didnt it happening, you can pass all your code to me and i will try replicate the error again, or watch the IntrinsicHeight parent if it have, or some other widget can affect your height and crash your programm, below is the code with a print that worked.
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();
  String ageErrorMessage = 'Invalid age';
  var selectedGender = 'Male';
  List<String> genders = ['Male', 'Female'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Age",
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 12 ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: ageController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: "Age",
                      isDense: true,
                      errorText: ageErrorMessage,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 12),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Gender",
                    //style: textStyle,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 12 ),
                  DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 14.5)),
                      hint: Text(
                        'Gender',
                        // style: textStyle,
                      ),
                      value: selectedGender,
                      //validator: validate,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      items: genders.map((String gender) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: gender,
                          child: Text(
                            gender,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String? value) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



if you see height of dropdown its somewhat larger than textfeild, I want to fix it

Okay if just this, add the same value in your both decoration > contentPadding TextFormField and Dropdown in this case add in your Textformfield:
decoration: const InputDecoration(                       border: OutlineInputBorder(),                       hintText: "Age",                       isDense: true,                       contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(                         horizontal: 8.0,                         vertical: 14.5,                       ),                     ),

@HiteshBharadwaj if resolve, please mark as solution/resolved or tell me, alright ?

no did not resolve

you can try using a fixed height for both TextField and Dropdown

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
